# Python tkinter listbox getting index

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I'm inserting some data into listbox and when I try to read that placed in index, the program is returning a consecutive numbers like 0,1,2,3 as index and not the id used in lb.insert.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
lb = tk.Listbox(root)
lb.insert(5,'data1')
lb.insert(8,'data2')
lb.insert(13,'data3')
lb.insert(55,'data4')
lb.insert(21,'data5')
but = ttk.Button(root,text='command',command=lambda:ReadIndex())
lb.pack()
but.pack()
def ReadIndex():
    index = lb.index(lb.curselection())
    print(index)
```

How can i get the index that wrote in .insert?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that doesn't depend on a database, and has correct indentation.  Use some hard-coded data that is in the exact format that `c.fetchall()` returns.

Comment: I gave another example to explain better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i get the index that wrote in .insert?

You can't.

The "id" that you think you're giving isn't an id, it's an index. And if the index is larger than the last index, it's ignored and the item is placed at the end.

In other words, when you do this:

```
lb.insert(5,'data1')
lb.insert(8,'data2')
```

Then `'data1` will be inserted at index 0 (zero), and `'data2'` will be inserted at index 1 (one). There is no way to retrieve the original values 5 and 8.

Comment: And if I insert a data1 like: ' 5, data1', ' 8, data2', '13, data3', can I read that two first chars?
I'm using that space(' ') with .format {:2}

Comment: @ThomasCaio: you can get back whatever you insert into the text widget